# iOS Developer Enterprise Program - Hosting on Web Server

Tags: ios, xcode, hosting, enterprise

I am new to this site, so bear with me. I just wanted to ask a quick question regarding the iOS Developer Enterprise Program. I am enrolled, and I have made a few apps that are ready for in-house distribution. I have uploaded the .plist and .ipa file to my website in a separate directory. However, whenever anybody tries to download it, they just get the error message "Could not connect to website.com". Then, when I open up Xcode and launch the console when my iPhone is connected and I try to download it, Xcode displays this: "Could not load download manifest with underlying error: (null)". The null part really throws me off. Everyone has iOS 7.1 (or mostly everyone), and the website does have an SSL certificate, so I can't figure out why it is showing that error. Any help with this would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out? I'm having the same issue and would appreciate any insight. Thanks!

Comment: @Jon Yes, it was just the SSL provider. For some reason the RapidSSL didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Was ready to give up and change SSL provider, but managed to get the reason for me. Hope this will help for someone:

Problem occurred because my server was responding `403 Forbidden` for manifest download request by Safari (because this request does not send cookies required for being authorised).

Answer (score -1):

You need to make sure that the website that hosts the `.plist` and the `.ipa` files uses https. This is a requirement in iOS 7.1 and above.

Comment: It does use https. The SSL certificate creates the secure connection. It is a RapidSSL, so maybe it's just the issuer of the SSL.